# Codeigniter - flashdata with routes not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, session, routes

here is a section of my `routes.php` file

```
$route['admin/login'] = 'admin_login';
$route['admin/login/(:any)'] = 'admin_login/$1';
$route['admin/logout'] = 'admin_login/logout';
$route['admin'] = 'admin_login';
$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'admin_login/$1';
```

a section of my `validate_login()` method in the `Admin_Login` controller

```
if(! $this->form_validation->run()) {
    $messages = validation_errors('<div class="alert error">',"</div>\r\n");
    $this->session->set_flashdata('messages', $messages);
    $this->session->keep_flashdata('messages');
    /* will redirect to admin_login/index */
    redirect('admin/login');
    return FALSE;
}
```

a section in the `index()` method in the `Admin_Login` controller

```
$data = array();
$data['messages'] = $this->session->flashdata('messages');
$this->load->view('admin/login', $data, true);
```

a section in the `admin/login.php' view

```
<div class="message_box">
<?php echo $messages; ?>
</div>
```

the `userdata` in the `$this->session` object

```
 [userdata] => Array
        (
            [session_id] => 1da231df3eb2ef90257b173bf34aa308
            [ip_address] => 192.168.1.135
            [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36
            [last_activity] => 1370231465
            [user_data] => 
            [flash:new:messages] => 
The Username field is required.


The Password field is required.



        )
```

Scenario:

When I login, The user input will be passed to `admin/validate_login`. I deliberately log in with empty credentials. the validation errors are expected in the views file. but it does not show. I have a hunch that the routes are causing this bug. Any help on this?

Solved:

Session class does not escape the flashdata properly. Encoded and Decoded with base64 to properly show the data.